# How to use use db_rewrite_sql() with db_query() in D7?

Tags: 7, database

I read article where it was written to use `db_rewrite_sql($query)`. In Drupal 7, you need to use `addTag('node_access')` along with `db_select().

I have  a query with 8 columns and 4 conditions; for simplicity I am using `db_query()`.

How can I use `db_rewrite_sql()` with `db_query()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use [db_select()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!database!database.inc/function/db_select/7) with the [addTag()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!database!select.inc/function/SelectQuery%3a%3aaddTag/7) modifier.

The query you mention doesn't sound too crazy so it should be fine for db_select().
The only downside is it can be a bit slower.

As per the [db_query()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!database!database.inc/function/db_query/7) api docs:

> Use this function for SELECT queries if it is just a simple query string. If the caller or other modules need to change the query, use db_select() instead.

Comment: is there no alternative to db_select() ? can I not write a query using db_query.

Comment: Not for a db_rewrite_sql() equivalent.